# Hangman Game Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a hangman program in python, I'm trying to print letters that the user has been guessing but I can't figure out how to do it, nothing seems to be working. I tried a function and a for loop but it doesn't print anything and at this point I don't know how else to do it. This is my code so far:

```
secretword=""
currentword=""
cw=""
hangcount=0

def hanging():
  if hangcount==1:
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
  elif hangcount==2:
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|        |")
  elif hangcount==3:
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       /")
  elif hangcount==4:
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       //")
  elif hangcount==5:
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|       /|")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       //")
  elif hangcount==6:
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|       /|/")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       //")

def clearscreen():
  for i in range(50):
    print

def displayCurrentword():
  global currentword
  cw=""
  for ch in currentword:
    cw=cw+ch+" "
  print (cw)

def initCurrentword():
  global currentword
  currentword=""
  for ch in secretword:
    currentword=currentword+"_"

def find_replace(letter):
  global currentword
  found=False
  cw=""
  for i in range(0,len(secretword)):
    if secretword[i]==letter:
      found=True
      cw=cw+letter
    else:
      cw=cw+currentword[i]
  currentword=cw
  if found==False:
    global hangcount
    hangcount+=1

print ("Welcome to Hangman!")
print
secretword=raw_input("Enter word:")
secretword=secretword.lower()

initCurrentword()

while (currentword!=secretword and hangcount<6):
  clearscreen()
  hanging()
  displayCurrentword()
  letter=raw_input("Enter a letter:")
  letter=letter.lower()
  find_replace(letter)
  displayCurrentword() 

if currentword==secretword:
  print ("Congrats you win!")
else:
  clearscreen()
  print ("----------")
  print ("|        |")
  print ("|       ---")
  print ("|      |   |")
  print ("|       ---")
  print ("|       /|/")
  print ("|        |")
  print ("|       //")
  print ("You killed him!")
  print ("The word was %s"%(secretword))
```

And if there's anything else I could change or improve let me know. 
Also, when I tried to put this slash "\" as an arm and a leg it wouldn't let me, it gave me an error and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: It worked for me just changed `raw_input` to just `input`... Was there another issue you were getting? (should also note this was in python 3)

Comment: Test the components of your program individually and try to figure out which specific part is misbehaving. You have a bunch of functions defined; see if each specific one does what it's supposed to.

Comment: to print a \ as an arm or leg use two slashes like \\. \ is a special escape character which is why this was giving you a different result than you expected

Comment: def clearscreen():
  for i in range(50):
    print
that does nothing. There are a few more print statements with no arguments.

Comment: It's a two player game, so def clear screen() is to move everything up out of the screen when you enter a word so the other person who's playing the game can't see the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, I think this is the simplest way to fix it is:

- add a global variable list `letters`
- append letters guessed to the list
- print the list at the end of each turn
- double backslashes `\\` to form the left arm and leg

I included a few other suggestions along with comments.
Hope this helps.

```
secretword=""
currentword=""
cw=""
hangcount=0
letters=[]  # declare letters list

def hanging():
    if hangcount==1:
        print ("----------")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|      |   |")
        print ("|       ---")
    elif hangcount==2:
        print ("----------")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|      |   |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|        |")
    elif hangcount==3:
        print ("----------")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|      |   |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       /")
    elif hangcount==4:
        print ("----------")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|      |   |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       / \\")  # double backslashes \\ for left leg
    elif hangcount==5:
        print ("----------")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|      |   |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|       /|")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       / \\")  # double backslashes 
    elif hangcount==6:
        print ("----------")
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|      |   |")
        print ("|       ---")
        print ("|       /|\\")  # double backslashes for left arm
        print ("|        |")
        print ("|       / \\")  # and left leg

def clearscreen():
    for i in range(50):
        print('\n')

def displayCurrentword():
    global currentword
    cw=""
    for ch in currentword:
        cw=cw+ch+" "
    print (cw)

def initCurrentword():
    global currentword
    currentword=""
    for ch in secretword:
        currentword=currentword+"_"

def find_replace(letter):
    global currentword
    found=False
    cw=""
    for i in range(0,len(secretword)):
        if secretword[i]==letter:
            found=True
            cw=cw+letter
        else:
            cw=cw+currentword[i]
    currentword=cw
    if found==False:
        global hangcount
        hangcount+=1

clearscreen()
print ("Welcome to Hangman!")
print
secretword=raw_input("Enter word:")
secretword=secretword.lower()

initCurrentword()

while (currentword!=secretword and hangcount<6):
    global letter                # use global letters list
    clearscreen()
    if len(letters) != 0:
        # display guessed letters (set() to remove duplicates)
        print("Guessed letters:", ', '.join(set(letters)))
        if hangcount == 0:
            print ("\n" * 4)     # empty space for hangman (for consitent layout)
    hanging()
    displayCurrentword()
    letter=raw_input("Enter a letter:")
    letter=letter.lower()
    letters.append(letter)       # add current letter to letters list
    find_replace(letter)
    displayCurrentword() 

if currentword==secretword:
    print ("Congrats you win!")
else:
    clearscreen()
    print("Guessed letters:", ', '.join(set(letters)))  # display guessed letters
    print ("----------")
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|      |   |")
    print ("|       ---")
    print ("|       /|\\")  # double backslashes 
    print ("|        |")
    print ("|       / \\")  # double backslashes 
    print ("You killed him!")
    print ("The word was %s"%(secretword))
```